# How to code in c# the action to take a screenshot of a specific region and paste it into clipboard?

Tags: c#, screenshot, clipboard, region

I'm currently using a macro recorder tool that cycles through an action many times. It works in VBA, I coded it, nothing too complicated. It takes "by hand" 2 screenshots of regions on the screen using the WINDOWS + SHIT + S command then pasting the image into a powerpoint document.

I have basically a list of capture points from a software and "exporting" all these points in a file via powerpoint.

My question is that my method is not very clean and too home-made. It works but takes so much time. In the macro recorder software I use there is a C# tool where one can run a code.

I wanted to know if it's possible to write a code that takes a screenshot of a specific region and pastes it in the clipboard ?

For example take a screenshot of a rectangle starting 520,340 and finishing at 1810,1045. Pasting that in clipboard. Basically doing exactly like the WINDOWS+SHIFT+S shortcut, but much cleaner and faster.

This is the code that I see in the C# tool.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

It also says **IMPORTANT : This code MUST contain a class named "Program" with a static method "Main".**

[image]

I tried to copy paste a few codes I found on this website, but alas it didn't work and unfortunately I am not versed in the art of C#. Any help will be greatly appreciated !

I tried to test with different code I found on internet, unfortunately I had errors messages of which I don't understand.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/2d2d83/how-to-capture-a-screen-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: To be honest, this sounds like you need to learn C#, before continuing with that task.
Download an IDE like VS Code or Visual Studio, read (or watch) some starter tutorials, etc.
If you don't know why you need a Program.cs and/or a Main method, this won't get cleaner than your current code.

Comment: I am a civil engineer and work on construction site and also on BIM models. It's in the context of these 3D models that I made this little macro in VBA. Now I'm just trying to optimize it and unfortunately don't have the time to learn C# and also I have never coded in the 15 years I've worked as a civil engineer. Just trying to get someone to help me, I thought that coding a screenshot action isn't too complex but maybe I am wrong it takes hundreds of lines.

Comment: @Nsevens unfortunately I tried this already but it doesn't work, but I can't understand why https://i.imgur.com/hCyjYYP.png